# Money transfer from a French bank to an Indian Bank

Tags: india, international-transfer, online-banking, france

I am a student in India. Recently, I attended a conference in Paris and the organizers will be reimbursing my travel through online bank transfer. However, they are insisting on IBAN/RIB no. Indian banks work through SWIFT code, but they are not able to understand this. I have provided my account no., branch and bank name along with the SWIFT code. Is there any other term for SWIFT code which is used in France ? Kindly help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your Organizers are not familiar with dealing transfers outside of Euro Zone. You are right IBAN is not used in India.

A Bank in France can initiate an International Wire. There are few Banks that offer this online, for most one has to visit the Branch. See this https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/2862/international-money-transfer-online-from-a-french-bank

I am not aware of any other term used in France for International Wire, try explaining; Its also called BIC. It would help if you also provide your Correspondent Bank details [This will be a Bank in Europe]. This should be available on your Indian Bank's website.